# MySQL inner join different results

Tags: mysql

I am trying to work out why the following two queries return different results:

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.id, i.date  
FROM `tblinvoices` i
INNER JOIN `tblinvoiceitems`  it ON it.userid=i.userid
INNER JOIN `tblcustomfieldsvalues`  cf ON it.relid=cf.relid  
WHERE i.`tax` = 0  
AND i.`date`  BETWEEN  '2012-07-01' AND '2012-09-31'
```

and

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.id, i.date  
FROM `tblinvoices` i
WHERE i.`tax` = 0  
AND i.`date`  BETWEEN  '2012-07-01' AND '2012-09-31'
```

Obviously the difference is the inner join here, but I don't understand why the one with the inner join is returning less results than the one without it, I would have thought since I didn't do any cross table references they should return the same results.

The final query I am working towards is

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.id, i.date  
FROM `tblinvoices` i
INNER JOIN `tblinvoiceitems`  it ON it.userid=i.userid
INNER JOIN `tblcustomfieldsvalues`  cf ON it.relid=cf.relid  
WHERE  cf.`fieldid` =5  
AND  cf.`value` 
REGEXP  '[A-Za-z]'
AND i.`tax` = 0  
AND i.`date`  BETWEEN  '2012-07-01' AND '2012-09-31'
```

But because of the different results that seem incorrect when I add the inner join (it removes some results that should be valid) it's not working at present, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

INNER JOIN statement will retrieve rows that are stored in both table of the jion statement.
Try a LEFT JOIN statement. This will return rows that are in first table but not necessary in the second one :

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.id, i.date  
FROM `tblinvoices` i
LEFT JOIN `tblinvoiceitems`  it ON it.userid=i.userid
LEFT JOIN `tblcustomfieldsvalues`  cf ON it.relid=cf.relid  
WHERE i.`tax` = 0  
AND i.`date`  BETWEEN  '2012-07-01' AND '2012-09-31'
```

Answer (score 2):

INNER JOIN means show only records where the same ID value exists in both tables.

LEFT JOIN means to show all records from left table (i.e. the one that precedes in SQL statement) regardless of the existance of matching records in the right table.

Try LEFT Join instead of INNER JOIN

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.id, i.date  
FROM `tblinvoices` i
LEFT JOIN `tblinvoiceitems`  it ON it.userid=i.userid
LEFT JOIN `tblcustomfieldsvalues`  cf ON it.relid=cf.relid  
WHERE i.`tax` = 0  
AND i.`date`  BETWEEN  '2012-07-01' AND '2012-09-31'
```

Comment: I have answered the similar question yesterday